# Implement drop function of an external element for Angular ui-calendar

Tags: jquery, angularjs, drag-and-drop, typescript, fullcalendar

I'm using the ui-calendar plugin provided for AngularJS, based on Fullcalendar jQueryUI plugin. What I want is to implement like Fullcalendar demos the drag and drop function, of external events. But it's not provided by default for Angular ui-calendar, so I made some researches.

Now I'm capable of drag an external element, put it onto the calendar, the calendar detect the element, but I don't know how to get this element to put it in the calendar.

Doc says that element can be retrived with `this` tag, but I've got nothing when I call `$(this).data('eventObject');`

Here my calendar controller (I use Typescript for AngularJS) :

```
export class CalendarCtrl {
    static $inject = ['planningService'];

    public events: any;
    public uiConfig: any;
    public alertMessage: string;
    public eventSources: any;
    public eventsPlanned: Array<EventPlanned>;

    constructor(planningService: PlanningService) {

        // events
        this.events = planningService.getEventsPlanned();

        /* config object */
        this.uiConfig = {
            calendar: {
                lang: 'fr',
                droppable: true,
                drop: this.onDrop,
                height: 450,
                editable: true,
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                eventClick: this.alertOnEventClick,
                eventDrop: this.alertOnDrop,
                eventResize: this.alertOnResize
            }
        };

        /* Event sources array */
        this.eventSources = [this.events];
    }

    public onDrop(date: Date, allDay: boolean) {
        alert('Dropped on Calendar ! AllDay: ' + allDay + ' Date: ' + date + ' ' + $(this).data('eventObject'));


        var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');

        var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

        copiedEventObject.start = date;
        copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;

        $('#interventionPlanning').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

        if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    }

    /* message on eventClick */
    public alertOnEventClick(event: any, allDay: any, jsEvent: any, view: any) {
        this.alertMessage = (event.title + ': Clicked ');
    }

    /* message on Drop */
    public alertOnDrop(event: any, dayDelta: any, minuteDelta: any, allDay: any, revertFunc: any, jsEvent: any, ui: any, view: any) {
        this.alertMessage = (event.title + ': Droped to make dayDelta ' + dayDelta);
    }

    /* message on Resize */
    public alertOnResize(event: any, dayDelta: any, minuteDelta: any, revertFunc: any, jsEvent: any, ui: any, view: any) {
        this.alertMessage = (event.title + ': Resized to make dayDelta ' + minuteDelta);
    }
}
```

My HTML :

```
<div class="wrapper wrapper-content" ng-controller="CalendarCtrl as calendar">
    <div id="interventionPlanning" ui-calendar="calendar.uiConfig.calendar" calendar="interventionPlanning" class="calendar" ng-model="calendar.eventSources"></div>
</div>
```

Is anyone has found a solution for this ? A lot of posts related to my problem exist, but I've found no solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found this:

```
        $scope.uiConfig = {
            calendar: {
                droppable: true,
                drop:function(data) {
                    alert("I got droped!" + new Date(data));
                }
            }
        };
```

I'm still working on it but you can find the solution from this point.

Good luck!